# How Does Swift Package Manager Accept a String Literal for Version in Package Dependencies?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm working with Swift Package Manager (SPM) to create a Swift command-line tool and have a question regarding the specification of package dependencies in Package.swift.

Here's a snippet of my Package.swift:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "FileCreator",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser", from: "1.3.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "FileCreator")
    ]
)
```

I am curious about the dependency declaration for swift-argument-parser:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser", from: "1.3.0")
```

In this line, the from parameter is specified using a string literal "1.3.0". However, I noticed that the from parameter is expected to be of type PackageDescription.Version.

My question is: How does SPM internally handle this string literal to convert it into a PackageDescription.Version? Is there an implicit conversion happening in the background, or is there some other mechanism at play that allows the direct use of a string literal for version specification?

Any insights or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.